# Non-square matrix in eigen during simulation

Tags: r, simulation, correlation

I have done `mvn` simulation with the `MASS` package.

Simulations should have the Mean and Variances of `X` and `Y` and a chosen correlation. SO far this works:

```
    K=0.1
    Sim <- data.frame(X,Y)
    CovM <- matrix(data=c(var(X),(-k)*sd(X)*sd(Y),(-k)*sd(X)*sd(Y),var(Y),ncol=2,nrow=2)
    MVSim <- mvrnorm(n, mu=colMeans(Sim), Sigma=CovM, empirical=TRUE)
```

Now I want to replicate the procedure with a for loop:

```
    for(i in seq(1,m, by=2)){
      MVSimOB[, i:(i+1)] <- mvrnorm(n, mu=colMeans(Sim), Sigma=CovM, empirical=TRUE)
```

But I get the following error message:

```
  Sigma = matrix(c(var(SimYOB),  : 
  Indices out of borders
```

The solution is probably very simple. But I do not understand why I first do not get an error, but replicating the procedure does not work.
Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Hi, you have forgotten the 'matrix' in the loop

Comment: Hey, I have edited my post now - unfortunately it still does not work!

Comment: hard to say where is the problem without reproductivle example, but obviously you covarance matrix is not the right size. You should check out your matrix before executing **mvnorm**

Comment: check your code, there is some miss parenthese :
CovM<-matrix(data=c(var(X),(-k)*sd(X)*sd(Y),(-k)*sd(X)*sd(Y),var(Y),ncol=2,nrow=2)

Comment: There must have been some problem with the covariance matrix. I did not find out what exactly. But naming the first run MVSim1 and using Sigma = Cov(MVSim1) in the loop, it worked. - Thanks for the help!

Comment: I was getting this same error using ZCA whiten functions in R.  I then saw that the methods implemented in python use a fudge factor (see https://martin-thoma.com/zca-whitening/ & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574782/how-to-whiten-matrix-in-pca/11336203#11336203).